# User being signed in with phone number even if they don't provide the sms code in firebase with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am running into a little bit of a problem here. Everything works fine in these scenarios for me:

1. User signs in and has a phone number with sms enabled, gets the verification code and puts in the right code. User is signed in.
2. User signs in and has a phone number with sms disabled. User is signed in without any sms process.
3. User signs in and has no phone number. User is signed in without any sms process.

what is not working correctly:

1. User signs in and has a phone number with sms enabled, puts in wrong verification code. User is not signed in. This is how I want it to work. Now if the user stays on the login page and signs in with his/her email and password it is as if the entire phone process is skipped and it logs them in. However it does not act as if it goes though with the `signInWithPhoneNumber` process.

For example in this scenario the user should be redirected to the home page through `this.setPage('home')`, but it nevers gets there, like I said it is as if it is being canceled out somehow, but the user is logged in.

---

**EDIT :**

A little more detail about this problem. If you look at the code you can see that no matter what the scenario a user will be alerted, whether he is logged in with or without sms. Also any errors are also alerts through the catch block. The reason it is hard for me to find this error is because there is no alert to the screen, it is as if it goes through the login with `signInWithPhoneNumber`, but the promise is just canceled and nothing else happens.

Two things should happen when a user is logged in, one a user should get a popup of whether they logged in with or without sms, second a user should be redirected to the home page. Both of these work in all the top 3 scenarios, but what happens for this 4th senario is no popup and no redirect. It is as if the code is being stopped some where after a user is logged in.

---

swal means sweetalert.

Here is the code:

```
login(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const email = this.loginEmail.value;
    const password = this.loginPsw.value;
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

    if (!this.verify) {
      swal({
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'You forgot to complete the reCAPTCHA',
        icon: 'error'
      });

      return;
    }

    fire
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        if (user.phoneNumber) {
          fire
            .database()
            .ref('2FA/' + user.uid)
            .once('value', snap => {
             // --> even if snap.val() is true after user puts in wrong sms 
             // this value does not matter it passes true , 
             // but then I do not see any of the promise sequence happen from 
             // signInWithPhoneNumber
              if (snap.val() === true) {
                fire
                  .auth()
                  .signInWithPhoneNumber(`${user.phoneNumber}`, appVerifier)
                  .then(confirmationResult => {
                    if (confirmationResult) {
                      swal({
                        closeOnClickOutside: false,
                        closeOnEsc: false,
                        title: 'Success',
                        text: 'Please provide use the verification code to continue',
                        icon: 'success',
                        buttons: true,
                        dangerMode: false,
                        content: {
                          element: 'input',
                          attributes: {
                            placeholder: 'Confirmation code here',
                            type: 'text'
                          }
                        }
                      })
                        .then(value => {
                          if (!value) {
                            throw new Error('Must provide a code to login.');
                            return;
                          }

                          return confirmationResult.confirm(value);
                        })
                        .then(response => {
                          return fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                        })
                        .then(user => {
                          swal({
                            title: 'Sucess',
                            text: `${user.email} signed in with sms verification`,
                            icon: 'success'
                          });

                          this.props.setPage('home');
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                          fire.auth().signOut();
                          this.loginForm.reset();

                          swal({ title: 'Oops...', text: `${err}`, icon: 'error' });
                        });
                    }
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    fire.auth().signOut();
                    this.loginForm.reset();

                    swal({ title: 'Oops...', text: `${err}`, icon: 'error' });
                  });
              }
            });

          return;
        }
        swal({
          title: 'Success',
          text: `${user.email} signed in without sms verification.`,
          icon: 'success'
        });
        this.props.setPage('home');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        fire.auth().signOut();

        swal({
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: `${err}`,
          icon: 'error'
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: A logical mistake ?? Your success call to `swal` after the `if (user.phoneNumber)` condition should be wrapped inside an `else` block. But it seems to be outside and executes regardless of the `phoneNumber` condition!!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I will try this out and see if it works!

Comment: @Panther that did not fix the problem, although I should include the if there, I will try to be a little more specific of what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that after this scenario happened:

`User signs in and has a phone number with sms enabled, puts in wrong verification code...` (Look in the question for more information about the matter)

The `appVerifier` was invalid because the captcha had not been reset after a fail. So technically there was a valid captcha just not a new one I suppose and this was causing the sms part of the code to just not happen. I'm not sure why it wasn't throwing an error, but anyhow, in the `catch` block of `signInWithPhone` promise I just needed to add:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(widgetId => {
  window.recaptchaVerifier.reset(widgetId);
});
```

This fixed it.